# Laravel + SPA VueJs not giving error for unknown component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
<template>
    <div>
     <test-component />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
//import TestComponent from '../path-to-components/TestComponent';
export default {
    name: 'SomeRandomComponent',
    components: {
        TestComponent,
    }
}
</script>
```

**Expected Behaviour**:
The application should give some console error if there is a problem with the imports or anything else similar to this.

**Current Behaviour**:
The page get blank in the browser and there is no error in console even if the import statement is commented out.

**Code for reference**

*app.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from '~/router';
import App from '~/components/App';

new Vue({
  router,
  ...App
})
```

*router.js*

```
export default [
    { path: '/some-path', name: 'testing', component: import( `~/pages/path-to-component`).then(m => m.default || m) },
]
```

*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <loading ref="loading" />
    
    <transition name="page" mode="out-in">
      <component :is="layout" v-if="layout" />
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Loading from './Loading'
// Load layout components dynamically.
const requireContext = require.context('~/layouts', false, /.*\.vue$/)

const layouts = requireContext.keys()
  .map(file =>
    [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.vue$)/g, ''), requireContext(file)]
  )
  .reduce((components, [name, component]) => {
    components[name] = component.default || component
    return components
  }, {})

export default {
  el: '#app',

  components: {
    Loading
  },

  data: () => ({
    layout: null,
    defaultLayout: 'default'
  }),

  metaInfo () {
    const { appName } = window.config

    return {
      title: appName,
      titleTemplate: `%s · ${appName}`
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.$loading = this.$refs.loading
  },

  methods: {
    /**
     * Set the application layout.
     *
     * @param {String} layout
     */
    setLayout (layout) {
      if (!layout || !layouts[layout]) {
        layout = this.defaultLayout
      }

      this.layout = layouts[layout]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you compile in dev or prod mode? Is your vue initiate propely? If you are following Laravel + Vue guide from Laravel website, you should have somewhere with something that look like this ```const app = new Vue({el: '#app', data() return {}});```. What is the content of this file?

Comment: It's in dev mode and the code do have `const app = new Vue({el: '#app', data() return {}});`

Comment: Can you provide us with the code. Where do you call the component you are showing us. If this component is not created, it can't try the test-component. So, provide the vue.js file and the file where you call that component (container, the one with the element with id #app).

Comment: I have updated the question with code for reference so that you can review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using Vue2 since Vue3 is in beta.

**The first problem** I see with your code, is that your `<div id="app">` is inside a Vue component.

[Declarative Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering)

What happening is that everything is compile, but you are trying to render Vue inside a component that does not exist.

Instead, create a div element inside the html or blade.php file that is loaded by the client. For my part, I use a blade layout like this:

```
//resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php

...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" v-cloak> //This is plain loaded when client render views, then, when script will initiate, Vue will be able to access everything inside this.
            <navbar v-bind:core="core"></navbar> //There is my navbar which is a Vue component.

            <div class="boxed">
                <div id="content-container">

                    @yield('content') //Blade component are injected there. since it's inside the <div id="app">, thoses component can include Vue directive/component.

                </div>
...
```

**Another thing** that seems a problem is that you are initiating Vue inside a Vue component. Things are that Vue is a package and compiled into javascript in the end. But, to make all the magic happen, you need to have somwhere to initiate all this. In that case, your App.js file should look something like this:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

This file is the one created by default by laravel for Vue template on fresh Laravel 8 install.

The difference between import and require is that import create a promise.

You don't want a promise there, because you want that file to be execute at the moment the client will begin to render your page.

Following thoses recommendation, I think you will be able to get your app working quickly and Vue will start logging error into your console.